# Facebook "Add to My Page" not there

Tags: facebook, iframe

I've made some facebook pages before, but I'm running in to a problem that I haven't had before. Usually, when someone asks me to dev a facebook page for them, it's linked to an account and all I have to do is add the developer app, make a few apps for the links on the side bar, then navigate to the apps I created and click 'add to my page'.

For some reason, this person today gave me their log-in and their account isn't really 'real' so-to-speak. I'm navigated to the page they created upon log-in and there is nothing else loaded, not even a search bar. I was able to add the developer app by navigating to Edit Info (search bar popped up). However I am unable to add any apps to this account. The 'Add to My Page' does not show up on any app pages I navigate to. Is this because the account doesn't really exist? There is a "Create Your Profile" link up near the Settings/Logout buttons.

Am I thinking about this wrong? Is there another way for me to add apps/sidebar tabs with an account like this?

I was thinking of telling the person to register the account fully since "If you create a profile for your business, your account may be disabled for violating our Terms of Use."

Let me know if any of you have any insight.

Thanks!

Comment: More info about this change can be found here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

facebook changes as usual

try my "fix" @ http://admine.eu/addapp.html

here is part of the source and actually all you need:

```
window.open(
  "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=" +
  document.getElementById("appid").value +
  "&next=" +
  document.getElementById("appurl").value,

  "PageTab","width=1000,height=300"
)
```

`+document.getElementById("appid")` is the id of your app
`+document.getElementById("appurl")` is the canvas or tab URL of your app

Comment: You have just saved my evening sir! Wasn't exactly as I expected, but maybe I'm not a well enough app developer for that... Anyway, it worked, so many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I run into this too. Sometimes as when a client adds me as an admin I have to like the app I made on its profile page then switch to page mode and go to edit the page>apps and it shows up in my list of apps.

If you have already added it once it may already be in that list as well but doesn't show up in the left navigation until you add it as a tab in the app settings while in Page mode.

I find that if there are more than 8 tabs in the navigation already FB won't automatically add it to the left nav.

-Ann

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a javascript snippet that is intended to be used as a bookmarklet. If you use the bookmarklet while on an application's page in the developers section, a new window will automatically open with the add to page-dialog. To use it, just copy the minified code from the repository below and create a new bookmark for "javascript:[the code]" (without the quotation marks).

https://github.com/Wehrzie/Add-Facebook-Application-to-Page-Bookmarklet

Hopefully this will help some until Facebook cleans up their current, quite messy, solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple to use:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&next=http://www.facebook.com

More info about what's going on:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/01/how-to--migrate-your-app-profile-page/