# Where is the Facebook "Add To Page" to add an App to a Fan Page

Tags: facebook, user-interface

1) I created a Facebook page http://www.facebook.com/WinePassionate

2) I created an App but didn't set any Canvas nor Page Tab URL.

But I keep reading that there supposed to be somewhere  a "Add to Page" and I cannot seems to find it.

==============
UPDATE

When I try using the standard process to add the App to my Page
(as suggested by Miguel), I get the following error:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

================================

The App Website URL is pointing to [WinePassionate.com](http://www.WinePassionate.com)

Again I have nothing set for "canvas" nor for "App on facebook".
Would that be the issue?

Comment: You can refer to [How to add tab application to a page with the “new auth dialog”](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8596217/how-to-add-tab-application-to-a-page-with-the-new-auth-dialog) for an answer. BTW, It's better to use search before asking...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook "Add to My Page" not there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271994/facebook-add-to-my-page-not-there)

Comment: +1 as a dupe of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8596217/how-to-add-tab-application-to-a-page-with-the-new-auth-dialog

Answer (score 2):

It changed, application don't get pages anymore, to add the application to a page use:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

more info here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Cheers!

Comment: The redirect url should be on the same domain as app domain ... i usually just use the url of the tab ... cheers!

Comment: What do you mean by "should be on the SAME DOMAIN as APP DOMAIN". I was under the impression that the URL should point to a real EXTERNAL URL site that should be displayed inside the actual Page (and that's what they call a Tab). What am I missing here ?  :--)

Answer (score 0):

"*2) I created an App but didn't set any Canvas nor Page Tab URL.* "
To be able to add your app as a page tab, you must specify settings for Page Tab.  At least the url is required (no tab name in settings will default to the app's name for display).

Comment: OK, so I just added http://www.winepassionate.com on the Page Tab URL. Where would I see that option to Add the App to my original Page ?

Comment: Use: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL, you can see this documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: It seems I'm a bit lost. So you are saying that I from within the App itself, on the Page Tab URL I have to type the URL you provided where I have to specify the ID of the App itself (I would have immagine it knew where I am ). Regarding the actual 2nd param of that URL, is that pointing to an "external site" or ... ??

Comment: You just type it in by hand into your browser and click submit!  Bam!  The app is now added as a page tab.

Answer (score 0):

First: Why do the apps we created not have the "Add to Page" options on them in first place like all the documentation shows us it should?
Second: Using that URL was confusing!

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetabapp_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

NOT YOUR URL at the end but this:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&next=http://www.facebook.com