# "Add to my page" link for app is missing

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, addition

I'm having problem with the FB app I created. When I go to the Community page (created by clicking the button Create Facebook Page) I can't find the "Add to my page" link. I can't put the app that I created to my fanpage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook "Add to My Page" not there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271994/facebook-add-to-my-page-not-there)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, it is true. You can no longer add tabs using that link. Besides that, facebook will remove all application profile pages on february 1st 2012. What can you do in order to add your tab is to access the following url:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL` (make sure you replace with your app id and the url). You will see there a drop down list with the pages you are administrator of. Choose the page you want and click the „add page tab” button. That's it.

More info on this you can find [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/).

Comment: You can also use http://www.addtab.info/ which is perhaps easier to remember :). But yeah, it does the same thing as above...

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the craziest things, why isn't there a button in the app developers panel? I've built a tool for myself too http://robertbak.com/tools . It redirects you to facebook.com after adding the app so you just need the ID (I find it faster this way).

Comment: It's really confusing from Facebook. Why would they do that :|

Answer (score 7):

For a simpler way to add apps to pages you can try the following link, which is using the same dialog what misterjinx has written about. It for now saves you some effort until you figure out what exactly to do.

http://admine.eu/addapp.html

Comment: Now many are used to the PageTab Dialog, and it is easy to use once you figure out how it is done. Facebook are constantly upgrading their apis, and I believe this might also eventually change sometime. If not for the community, things do get difficult for non developers or the people who are just looking to hook up something & be done with it :)